# VBA Error in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with this code piece?

```
Target.Validation.Formula1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Formula
```

Sorry, i'm newbie in excel vba

Comment: "Number of incorrect arguments or invalid property assignment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `Validation.Formula1` is read-only and cannot be written to.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.validation.formula1.aspx

Comment: :( I can't set a formula dynamically?

Comment: @WilkerIceri Not that one.  I haven't done it before, but you probably have to make a new Validation object and then replace the current one.